# What does this syntx mean: if not ( x % n ):

Tags: python

I have a piece of code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for n in range(2,x):
            if not ( x % n ):
                return False
    else:
        return True
```

I am confused by the line `if not ( x % n ):`

I know % is module and gives the remainder.
I'm confused because I thought there had to be something for it to compare to like: 
`if x%n == y:`

Can someone explain what exactly `if not ( x % n ):` means?

Comment: Because of falsy values in any programming language, in this case for python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/3558900 as you can see, 0 is a falsy value.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/2285236

Comment: If `x` is divisible by `n` the term `x % n` will return `0` and `not 0` in python is evaluated to `True` - this will cause the function to return `False` since `x` is not a prime. And you're right you could substitute `if not ( x % n )` with: `if x % n == 0`

Comment: so is the default 0 if your do not specify a number for it to be equal to?

Comment: @KatherineGibson no. Truth value testing does not require equality testing, i.e. `a == b`. Indeed, in Python, **any** object can be evaluated for a truth value.